# QueryDSL sql and UUID parameter type

Tags: postgresql, querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL SQL with `PostgresTemplates` and I'm trying to put UUID parameter into query, but when I'm executing this query:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
QOrganization org = QOrganization.organization;
long count = new SQLQuery(connection, configuration)
            .from(org)
            .where(org.id.eq(uuid))
            .count();
```

Database complains:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: there is no operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
```

How can I explicitly cast my UUID parameter?

Comment: PostgreSQL is frustratingly strict about some types, especially where most programming languages don't have matching types.  This appears to be one such case. You can create an implicit cast from text to uuid - I've written other examples for xml, json, etc, so search for *postgresql create implicit cast xml* or similar. Or you can set PgJDBC to pass text parameters as unknown-type, but that's a very big hammer as it applies to all queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querydsl SQL maps currently UUID types to PreparedStatements via setString. It looks like Postgres supports setting UUIDs directly via setObject, so some tuning of UUID support in Querydsl SQL seems to be needed.

Comment: Thank you! After overriding `UtilUUIDType.setValue` method to set parameter via setObject it workes as expected

Comment: I also fixed it directly in Querydsl https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/912